# Join two objects just like SQL inner join

Tags: javascript, arrays, object-literal

I have two objects like:

```
countries = [
    { id: 1, name: 'India', image: 'thumb15.jpg' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Africa', image: 'thumb11.jpg' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Kenya', image: 'thumb10.jpg' }
];

cities = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Ahmedabad', country_id: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Vadodara', country_id: 1 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Cairo', country_id: 2 },
    { id: 4, name: 'Kinshasa', country_id: 2 },
    { id: 5, name: 'Luanda', country_id: 2 },
    { id: 6, name: 'Nairobi', country_id: 3 },
    { id: 7, name: 'Nakuru', country_id: 3 },
    { id: 8, name: 'Mombasa', country_id: 3 },
];
```

I want to combine these two Objects, just like **SQL** have `INNER JOIN`

for example, I want to perform below operation (query) on the above two objects,

```
SELECT * from countries INNER JOIN cities ON cities.country_id = countries.id
```

and my expected output will look like:

```
expected_result = [
    { id: 1, name: "Ahmedabad", country_id: 1, country_name: "India", country_image: "thumb15.jpg" },
    { id: 2, name: "Vadodara", country_id: 1, country_name: "India", country_image: "thumb15.jpg" },
    { id: 3, name: "Cairo", country_id: 2, country_name: "Africa", country_image: "thumb11.jpg" },
    { id: 4, name: "Kinshasa", country_id: 2, country_name: "Africa", country_image: "thumb11.jpg" },
    { id: 5, name: "Luanda", country_id: 2, country_name: "Africa", country_image: "thumb11.jpg" },
    { id: 6, name: "Nairobi", country_id: 3, country_name: "Kenya", country_image: "thumb10.jpg" },
    { id: 7, name: "Nakuru", country_id: 3, country_name: "Kenya", country_image: "thumb10.jpg" },
    { id: 8, name: "Mombasa", country_id: 3, country_name: "Kenya", country_image: "thumb10.jpg" }
];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please learn [the difference between JSON and the Array or Object Literal Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation).

Comment: Thanks @str. I'll read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use `map` function and `Map` collection to get desired country:

```
const uniqueCountries = new Map(countries.map(s => [s.id, s]));
const result = cities.map(s => ({ ...s, 
    country_name: uniqueCountries.get(s.country_id).name }));
```

An example:

```js
let countries = [
    { id: 1, name: 'India', image: 'thumb15.jpg' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Africa', image: 'thumb11.jpg' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Kenya', image: 'thumb10.jpg' }
];

let cities = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Ahmedabad', country_id: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Vadodara', country_id: 1 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Cairo', country_id: 2 },
    { id: 4, name: 'Kinshasa', country_id: 2 },
    { id: 5, name: 'Luanda', country_id: 2 },
    { id: 6, name: 'Nairobi', country_id: 3 },
    { id: 7, name: 'Nakuru', country_id: 3 },
    { id: 8, name: 'Mombasa', country_id: 3 },
];

 const uniqueCountries = new Map(countries.map(s => [s.id, s]));
 const result = cities.map(s => ({ ...s, 
     country_name: uniqueCountries.get(s.country_id).name }));
 console.log(result);
```

**UPDATE:**

[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method **creates new array** from the calling array. In addition, you can add new properties to your object you want:

```js
let countries = [
    { id: 1, name: 'India', image: 'thumb15.jpg' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Africa', image: 'thumb11.jpg' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Kenya', image: 'thumb10.jpg' }
];

const countriesWithShortCountryNames = countries.map(s=> ({...s, 
   shortName: s.name.substring(0, 3)}))
console.log(countriesWithShortCountryNames)
```

[Map collection:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

> The Map object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original
>   insertion order of the keys.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. This solution also worked for me, but I didn't aware of javascript `map` and `Map` collection. So I didn't understand. Can you please provide some information to learn this concept.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a hash table for all items of `countries`, where `id` is the key and the value is a new object in the wanted format.

```
{
    1: {
        country_name: "India",
        image: "thumb15.jpg"
    },
    2: {
        country_name: "Africa",
        image: "thumb11.jpg"
    },
    3: {
        country_name: "Kenya",
        image: "thumb10.jpg"
    }
}
```

Then map a new objects with the original key/value and new properties from the hash table.

Methods used, in order of appearance:

- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with [assigning to new variable name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names)
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var countries = [{ id: 1, name: 'India', image: 'thumb15.jpg' }, { id: 2, name: 'Africa', image: 'thumb11.jpg' }, { id: 3, name: 'Kenya', image: 'thumb10.jpg' }],
    cities = [{ id: 1, name: 'Ahmedabad', country_id: 1 }, { id: 2, name: 'Vadodara', country_id: 1 }, { id: 3, name: 'Cairo', country_id: 2 }, { id: 4, name: 'Kinshasa', country_id: 2 }, { id: 5, name: 'Luanda', country_id: 2 }, { id: 6, name: 'Nairobi', country_id: 3 }, { id: 7, name: 'Nakuru', country_id: 3 }, { id: 8, name: 'Mombasa', country_id: 3 }],
    countriesH = countries.reduce((r, { id, name: country_name, ...o }) =>
        (r[id] = { country_name, ...o }, r), {}),
    result = cities.map(o => ({ ...o, ...countriesH[o.country_id] }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. This solution worked for me, but I didn't understand what you have done. Can you please explain it to me.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [a library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blinq) (which emulates dotnet's linq) which makes this a breeze:

```
import { blinq } from "blinq";
//...    
const joinedData = blinq(countries)
  .join(
    cities,
    co => co.id,
    ci => ci.country_id,
    (country, city) => ({ country, city })
  )
  .toArray();
```

```js
const {
  blinq
} = window.blinq;

const countries = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "India",
    image: "thumb15.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Africa",
    image: "thumb11.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Kenya",
    image: "thumb10.jpg"
  }
];

const cities = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Ahmedabad",
    country_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Vadodara",
    country_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Cairo",
    country_id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Kinshasa",
    country_id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Luanda",
    country_id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Nairobi",
    country_id: 3
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Nakuru",
    country_id: 3
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "Mombasa",
    country_id: 3
  }
];

const joinedData = blinq(countries)
  .join(
    cities,
    co => co.id,
    ci => ci.country_id,
    (country, city) => ({
      country,
      city
    })
  )
  .toArray();

console.log(JSON.stringify(joinedData, null, 2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/blinq"></script>
```